# $.post in a success $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there any way to have a $.post within a success callback of a $.post again. If the first $.post is not successful i will ask for prompt. If confirmed it call perform another $.post again

my code is as below

```
postvars = {
                order_no:order_no,
                tracking_no:tracking_no,
                continue_submit: false
            };  

url =  '../shipment/shipment_submit_order_status_ajax';  

  $.post(url, postvars, function(data1) {
        if(data1.status == "success")
        {
            alert("Order submitted 1");
        }
        else if(data1.status != "success")
        {
            var r = confirm("The Order is NOT ready to be shipped. Please check the order again. Are you sure you want to continue to ship this?");
            if(r)
            {
                //Submit order
                postvars = {
                    order_no:order_no,
                    tracking_no:tracking_no,
                    continue_submit: true
                };  

                url =  '../shipment/shipment_submit_order_status_ajax';

                $.post(url, postvars, function(data) { 
                    if(data.status == "success")
                    {
                        alert("Order submitted 2");
                    }
                }, 'json');  
            }
        }

    }, 'json');
```

it is executing both calls instead of prompting a confirm dialog first before executing the 2nd ajax call. Anyone has any solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: instead of alert your data for debug, you can use console.log('this my debug string') and see this data in browser console (cmd + j on mac)

Comment: The 2nd AJAX call is being issued _before_ the confirm?  That doesn't make sense.  Try using break points in the debugger; whatever your problem is you should witness that this is being executed in the correct order.

Comment: @edelweiss I tried your code, worked as expected, confirm dialog come. Can you write down server method accepting postvars?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to you using deffered objects in jQuery:

```
function ajaxMe(data){
    var df = $.Deferred();
    $.post('my_const_url', data, function(resp){
        if(resp.status !== 'success'){
            df.resolve(other_data);
        }else{
            df.reject(other.data);
        }
    }, 'json');
    return df.promise();
}

ajaxMe(postvars).done(function(response_data){
    ajaxMe(whatever_you_want);
}).fail(function(){
    var r = confirm("Do you really want it ?");
    if(r){
       ajaxMe(some_data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of 'if(r)' use 'if(true===r)'

Because in javascript 'if(r)' means whether the variable 'r' is defined. In this case this variable 'r' is defined and therefore the 'if' part is satisfied.

Comment: Why the down vote?!!! Should I have created a fiddle for this little bit problem. Now that will be overdoing it, surely?

Comment: If (r) is a truthyness test, not a test of whether the variable is defined.  It will not be satisfied if the confirm box was cancelled.